# Why the Integrating Factor is $\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

If we have a Differential Equation of the form $$Mdx+Ndy=0$$ which is not Eaxct and $Mx+Ny \ne 0$

If the equation is Homogenous

Why is the Integrating Factor $\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$ ?

My attempt:

Let $g(x,y)$ Be the Integrating Factor to make the equation exact.

Then we have

$$Mgdx+Ngdy=0$$ an Exact Differential Equation. So

$$\frac{\partial(Mg)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial(Ng)}{\partial x}$$ $\implies$

$$M\frac{\partial(g)}{\partial y}+g \frac{\partial(M)}{\partial y}=N\frac{\partial(g)}{\partial x}+g\frac{\partial(N)}{\partial x}$$

Any clue here to prove $g=\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$

Comment: This question would need the characterization of "the equation is homogeneous" to get a useful answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if an answer from @Goncalo is still considered "might be good or bad" by the community bot then it is totally hopeless.

Answer (score 2):

A first order ODE of the form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is said to be homogeneous if $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation)). Thus, if $N\neq 0$, it follows that$^{(*)}$
$$
\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}=f\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right). \tag{1}
$$
Therefore, multiplying the ODE by $(Mx+Ny)^{-1}$, we obtain
$$
Pdx+Qdy=0, \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
P=\frac{f\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y}, \qquad Q=\frac{1}{xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y}. 
\tag{3}
$$
To prove that $(2)$ is exact,
we have to show that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$. Indeed,
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}
=\frac{\frac{1}{x}f'\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y}
-\frac{f\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\left(f'\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+1\right)}{\left(xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y\right)^2}
=\frac{\frac{y}{x}f'\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-f\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{\left(xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y\right)^2} \tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=-\frac{f\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\frac{y}{x}f'\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{\left(xf\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+y\right)^2}
=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}. \quad{\square}\tag{5}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ Proof of $(1)$: Since $M$ and $N$ have the same degree of homogeneity, we have (for $\lambda\neq 0$)
$$
\frac{M(\lambda x, \lambda y)}{N(\lambda x,\lambda y)}=\frac{\lambda^nM(x,y)}{\lambda^nN(x,y)}=\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}. \tag{P1}
$$
In particular, taking $\lambda=x^{-1}$ in $(\text{P1})$ yields
$$
\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}=\frac{M(1, x^{-1} y)}{N(1, x^{-1} y)}, \tag{P2}
$$
from which follows $(1)$.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{1}{Mx+ Ny}$ is an integrating factor if and only if $\frac{1}{Mx+ Ny}\left(Mdx+ Ndy\right)$ is exact.  In order for that to be true we must have $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{M}{Mx+ Ny}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{M}{Mx+ Ny}$.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}M(Mx+ Ny)^{-1}= -\frac{MN}{(Mx+ Ny)^2}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}N(Mx+ Ny)^{-1}= -\frac{MN}{(Mx+ Ny)^2}$

Yes, assuming M and N are constants, then that is an integrating factor.

Comment: But if $M,N$ are constant, you do not need an integrating factor, $F(x,y)=Mx+Ny$ is already the integral.