# A question about ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

How to prove that $\frac{1}{xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)}$ is an integrating factor of a homogeneous linear differential equation $P(x,y)$d$x+Q(x,y)$d$y=0$?

I have seen a proof:

Suppose that $Q \neq 0$, multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac{1}{Q}$, then:

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=-\frac{P}{Q}=-g(\frac{y}{x})$$

$$g(\frac{y}{x})\text{d}x+\text{d}y=0$$

(Here is the first place that I cannot understand, why does it equal $-g(\frac{y}{x})$.)

Let $y=ux$, then $\text{d}y=u\text{d}x+x\text{d}u$, then

$$(g(u)+u)\text{d}x+x\text{d}u=0$$

Multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac{1}{x}$, we get

$$\frac{g(u)+u}{x}\text{d}x+\text{d}u=0$$

(Also I don't understand the reason why it multiplies $\frac{1}{x}$, how can we know that it simplifies the calculation.)

The equation has an integrating factor with respect only to $u$ since

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial\dfrac{g(u)+u}{x}}{\partial u}}{-\dfrac{g(u)+u}{x}}=-\dfrac{g^{\prime}(u)+1}{g(u)+u}$$

where denominator the is nonzero, let it be $\lambda(u)=\frac{1}{g(u)+u}$.

Therefore the initial equation has an integrating factor in form:

$$\mu(x,y)=\frac{1}{Q}\frac{1}{x}\lambda(u)=\frac{1}{xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)}$$

with $xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)\neq 0$.

And is there any easier way to understand the integrating factor?

Comment: $P(x,y)/Q(x,y)=x^{\deg P-\deg Q}P(1,y/x)/Q(1,y/x)=P(1,y/x)/Q(1,y/x)=g(y/x)$ since $P,Q$ are homogeneous of the same degree.  Now separate variables.

Comment: thanks! I knew that a homogeneous equation is in form y'+p(x)y=0, but I didnt know that here P,Q are of the same degree.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220334/proving-that-a-function-mu-x-y-is-an-integrating-factor-of-a-first-order-ho?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893198/why-the-integrating-factor-is-frac1mxny/4769291#4769291.